# Sum fields in sqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I recently upgraded to the most recent version of sqlalchemy and some of my code no longer works. I'm having difficulty finding how to fix it and could use a hand.

Previously the query appeared as so.

```
self.db.query(Drive).filter(Drive.package_id==package.package_id)\
    .filter(Drive.wipe_end!=None).sum(Drive.wipe_end - Drive.wipe_start)
```

this worked before to retrieve the sum of some durations but now I get the following error:

```
'Query' object has no attribute 'sum'
```

Any googling I do gets me information that is several years old.

Answer (score 22):

I believe you need the sum() function in the "func" package:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
cursor = self.db.query(func.sum(Drive.wipe_end - Drive.wipe_start)).filter(Drive.package_id==package.package_id).filter(Drive.wipe_end!=None)
total = cursor.scalar()
```

Comment: why did you use scalar? How would you round the number off ?

Comment: I get ``TypeError: 'BaseQuery' object is not callable`` in Python 3 with SQLAlchemy 1.12 with: ``votes_sum = VotesReleases.query(func.sum(VotesReleases.Vote)).filter_by(ReleaseID=release_id).all()``. Or does ``func.sum()`` not represent the SQL ``SUM()``?

Comment: I discovered the syntax for modern SQLAlchemy. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 16):

In SQLAlchemy 1.1.13 (released 3 August 2017), the syntax for using `sum()` is this:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
from apps.mystuff.models import MyModel

some_value = "hello"

result = MyModel.query.with_entities(
             func.sum(MyModel.MyColumn).label("mySum")
         ).filter_by(
             MyValue=some_value
         ).first()

# Depending on the column datatype, it's either int:
print(result.mySum)

# Or if the data is decimal/float:
print(float(result.mySum))
```

The main difference compared to the original answer is that instead of:
`query(func.sum())`

The syntax has changed to this starting from version 0.6.5:
`query.with_entities(func.sum())`

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.with_entities

Comment: yehh, This works fine without any error!!