# sum over a field on a query

Tags: sqlalchemy, func

this should be a asked-before question, I searched but I could not find any answer on that. Sorry if it is duplicated. I have a query lets say:

```
my_query=session.query(Item).filter(somefilter)
```

Now, Item has a column, lets say `counter`, and I want to find the sum of this column of `my_query`.
I can do that like this:

```
sum=0
for row in query:
    sum+=row.counter
```

but I don't this this is the efficient way of doing this specially in a large database. I know that this is possible: [sqlalchemy simple example of `sum`, `average`, `min`, `max`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830980/sqlalchemy-simple-example-of-sum-average-min-max), but this requires filtering on `qry` (borrowed from the page) which I have already given the filtered version `my_query`. I dont know if it is really more efficient to do the filtering again on top of `qry` v.s. using the for loop on `my_query`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292752/sum-fields-in-sqlalchemy?rq=1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same question.  I asked on irc.freenode.org#sqlalchemy and inklesspen pointed me to [Query#with_entities()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.with_entities).

```
sum = my_query.with_entities(func.sum(Item.counter)).scalar()
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a whole bunch of SQL "group" functions in sqlalchemy.func:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
my_query = session.query(func.sum(Item.counter)).filter(somefilter)
```

Comment: Hi Ketouem, I think in this case, you should filter on top of the query, while what I was asking was summing on an already existed query...